# Difficulty in understanding and correcting error messages

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have tried for several minutes now to correct an error that appears in the code after I have added the  `extractOperand` method. I can't find any syntactical or logical errors. Also, I notice that `extractOpcode` will not produce an error while the methods are practically the same. My guess now is that the error has to do with the placement of the function.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Micro86 {
    static int[] Memory = new int[20];
    static int accumulator = 0,
                instruction_pointer = 0,
                flags = 0,
                instruction_register = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String m86File = args[0];

        bootUp();
        loader(m86File);
        memoryDump();
    }

    public static void bootUp()
   {
        for(int i : Memory)
            i = 0;
   }

    public static void memoryDump()
    {
        for(int i: Memory)
            System.out.println(left_pad_zeros(Integer.toHexString(i)));
    }

    public static String registerDump()
    {
        return "Registers acc: " + accumulator
               + " ip: " + instruction_pointer
               + " flags: " + flags
               + "ir: " + instruction_register + "\n";
    }

    public static void loader(String file)
    {

        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(file));
            for(int i = 0; sc.hasNextInt() ; ++i){
                Memory[i] = sc.nextInt(16);
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot open file");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static int extractOpCode(int instruction)
    {
        return instruction >>> 16;
    }

    public static String left_pad_zeros(String str)
    {
        while(str.length() < 8)
            str = "0" + str;
        return str;
    }

    public static int extractOperand(int instruction)
    {
        return instruction <<< 16;
    }

}
```

ERROR:

```
Micro86.java:71: illegal start of type
    return instruction <<< 16;
                           ^
Micro86.java:71: illegal start of expression
        return instruction <<< 16;
                                 ^
    Micro86.java:71: ';' expected
            return instruction <<< 16;
                                  ^
    Micro86.java:74: reached end of file while parsing
    }
     ^
4 errors
```

Comment: @jpw that's interesting, then why didn't i get the same error for extractOpcode method ? I did >>> at that point

Comment: Very simply, there is no such operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this line in the `extractOperand` method:

```
return instruction <<< 16;
```

Even though there is an unsigned right shift operator `>>>`, there is no unsigned left shift operator `<<<`, because there is no sign-extension to perform when shifting left.  You can use the normal left shift operator, `<<`:

```
return instruction << 16;
```